# Expressão não funciona em Include no Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-6

Tentei fazer a seguinte expressão

```
var listag = db.grupo.Include(x => x.Itens).ToList();
```

A mesma não funciona dessa forma, mas se eu passar dessa forma:

`db.grupo.Include("Itens").ToList();`, assim funciona, por que? o que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: Não compila dessa forma

Comment: Qual o erro, usando da primeira forma?

Comment: ele nem reconhece a expressão no visual studio

Comment: Error 5 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: Deu certo usando System.Data.Entity, obrigado =)

Comment: @TiagoSilva Quer responder? Só pra pergunta não ficar em aberto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A implementação de `Include()` usando um tipo delegado está no `namespace System.Data.Entity` para o caso do Entity Framework, ou então `System.Linq`, se você estivesse usando `Linq`, que não é o seu caso.

Conforme apontado pelo @TiagoSilva em comentário, confira o cabeçalho do `Controller` se nele tem as seguintes declarações:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
```